# Как ввести переменную в запрос mysql и вывести другую

Tags: php, sql

Господа, нужна помощь в формулировке запроса к базе или может быть совет как более грамотно все организовать.
Дано 2 таблицы sql в первой хранятся данные о чертежах таблица формата id|ch|onop|twop|thop| в колонках |onop|twop|thop| содержаться расценки на каждую операцию. Вторая же таблица это отчет за день(история) с использованием данных из первой таблицы формата |operator|detal|operaciya|cena| которая заполняется из обычной веб формы из селектов и одного выпадающего списка из бд. Вот вопрос, все это дело выводиться в html морду и все бы было здорово но нужно как то записать цену операции каждого изделия, и вот тут я спасовал как ето сделать без понятия.
В историю пишется все замечательно через джойны, но переменная из селекта с выбором операции пишеться в базу с именем колонки.Как лучше всего привязать цену к конкретной операции и конкретной детали да и так что бы номер операции выводился.Все это хозяйство на старом php 5.6.Мне просто нужен дельный совет или хотя бы какая нибудь помощь,перерыл кучу литературы по sql и пхп и убил на это неделю уже хотя я уверен что реализовать это проще простого

Comment: простите, не по теме, но грамматика и орфография - огонь :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем я победил поставленную задачу добавлением еще одной таблицы которая указывает какие данные к какой операции относятся, не самый легкий способ но работает.Выборку произвожу `select * from |таблица указывающая какому чертежу какую операцию брать| , |таблица с "историей"| LEFT JOIN |таблица со списком чертежей| ON |id детали| = id left join |номер операции| on |операция из истории| = |id операции с таблицей указывающей какое значение у каждой операции|`
Думаю это понадобиться тому кто понял чего именно я хотел добиться)Остальным спасибо за внимание и особенно Ruslan_Semenov за наводку на Left Join

Answer (score 0):

У вас две таблицы:

в первой (table1) описаны детали, ее заполняете только деталями.

Во второй(table2) операции в нее и пишете вид операций, с указанием в колонке detal (id первой колонки)

При выводе делаете перекрестный запрос к примеру так:

```
SELECT table2.*
FROM table2 
   LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.id=table2.detal
```

Ну и выводите результат.

Comment: думал в этом направлении но встал вопрос в том как вывести в веб морду, там таблица в которой берутся данные через джойн на основе с таблицы истории со колонками |дата |оператор |деталь |цена/шт|  и я не знаю как вот подсунуть именно цену в эту таблицу, или перефразировать если то как сказать скрипту что нужно брать данные с колонки с второй операции например

Comment: в эту таблицу вывожу запросом `$strSQL = "select * from chertesh,cnc where detal=id
iner
";
$res = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {`
echo '<tr> и через row в каждый столбец свои данные, в целом все корректно выводиться но как цену вставить сюда ума не приложу

Comment: Так из написанного выше я вижу что данные из второй таблицы не берутся. $strSQL = "select * from chertesh LEFT JOIN chertesh ON chertesh.id=cnc.detal where detal=id";  Вот так пробуйте и добавится колонка cena

Comment: в целом у меня вышло `select * from oi JOIN chertesh ON id = id_ch where id_ch=id`  и да вы были правы колонки появились но вместе  с ними появился вопрос  сейчас у меня выводятся |onop|twop|thop| допустим, как теперь к ним привязать колонку operaciya из таблицы истории где записан номер этой операции что бы в результате выводилась только одно нужное нам значение.Или может быть лучше изменить значения в  списке селекта операции сейчас там выводиться тупо названия колонок операций то есть onop,twop.

Comment: или вот решил попробовать обходным путем в скрипте обработчике заполнения история сразу подменить значения переменными и по ним найти искомое 
`$cena = mysql_query(" select '".$operaciya."'` from oi  LEFT JOIN chertesh ON id = '".$detal."' ");
$cena=$_POST['cena'];
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cnc (operatorname, cena, operaciya, detal, colvodetal, brakop, data, brakotk)
VALUES('".$operatorname."', '".$cena."', '".$operaciya."', '".$detal."', '".$colvodetal."', '".$brakop."', '".$data."', '".$brakotk."')");` но и здесь потерпел фиаско, в админе запрос работает а в скрипте нет(

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос, ничего не понял, тем более что опять новые таблицы. И нужно использовать не JOIN а LEFT JOIN и первой указать таблицу в которой операции присоединяй к ней таблицы с данными. Уточнение, указывайте данные которые нужно вытянуть, и ничего лишнего не появится.

Comment: на данный момент три таблицы cnc-история в которую пишутся данные с привязкой к дате chertesh с данными чертежей в формате ID|описание чертежа и третья это расценки операций в формате id|oneop|twop.У каждой операции на каждую деталь своя цена, в форме заполняются из селектов Оператор,Деталь,Номер операции, и вот вопрос как привязать цену(выбора ее нет и тот кто заполняет форму ее не знает) ? селект с выбором операции где в values просто имя колонки из третьей таблицы, нечего умнее не придумал но уверен что решение на виду так как не думаю что я первый кто с такой задачей столкнулся

Comment: Если таблиц три, то делаем SELECT * FROM cnc LEFT JOIN chertesh ON chertesh.id = cnc."название колонки содержащий ид чертежа" LEFT JOIN "третья таблица" ON "третья таблица".id = cnc."название колонки содержащий ид третей таблицы" . Вот почитайте http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/LEFT_JOIN_optimisation.html

Comment: остался последний штрих, как сравнить имя колонки и значение колонки? что бы операция указывала из какой колонки взять значение [принт 1](http://pastenow.ru/b0f571a73d6f4cdc78e4c8cf8f2c2b2e) и [принт 2](http://pastenow.ru/3efce96cef694de9cbfaa0d1c62f7249) и я крайне признателен Вам за ваше терпение

Comment: Ничего не понимаю )

Comment: ну вот к примеру на скрине втором в колонке operaciya значение 2 и есть колонка 2 нужно вывести для id 1 значение 7

Comment: Так назовите колонки не 1 2 3